# I changed my valve gasket and spark plugs. But what is this noise it makes now?

Tags: troubleshooting, noise

So, I have replaced my valve cover gasket, as well as the spark plugs, in a 1003 Ford Tempo (apparently most of these have died already!)

However, after adjustment, I am getting a sound.  I do not particularly remember this sound from beforehand, and I don't really know what causes it.

Here is an upload of the sound:
[abnormal noise](https://vocaroo.com/i/s1vDo2KyXnxR)

I apologize for the low quality of the recording, but the "back and fourth sound" is somehow louder in real life, at least a bit.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you leave something in there while changing the gasket? Fluids ok?

Comment: I can´t help you with the noise, but as trick to locate it further is to take a metal rod or a stick and press one end against your ear and the other one against different parts of your engine.

Answer (score 1):

You say 'after adjustment' What adjustments have you made? I do not know this car model but assume you mean you have adjusted the valve clearences?

If so.. recheck them, as the noise from what I can hear sounds like a noisy tappet (excessive valve clearence.) Firstly though, check in the user manual whether these clearences are supposed to be checked/adjusted with the engine hot or cold. Doing these adjustments at the wrong temperature stage can cause such noise as effectively the valve gap is set at the wrong temperature, thus likely leaving the gaps set up wrongly thus giving you a tapping noise.